# Azure Data Factory Pipeline dependencies

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have several Azure Pipelines copying 1:1 data from source tables to destination tables once a day. Let's call these "Phase 1 tables". This part works fine.

I also have a fact table that is loaded once a day from a complex view that joins columns from all of the "Phase 1 tables". Lets call this "Phase 2".

As the Output-data-sets of "Phase 1 tables" are tables, and input-data-set of the "Phase 2" is a view, I had found no way to chain the dependencies by using same data-sets.

My problem is that "Phase 1 tables" are loaded by default at 00:00:00 UTC, and take a variable amount of time to finish. Typically between 20 to 30 minutes.

I would like the "Phase 2 table" to not run in parallel with "Phase 1 tables". By default "Phase 2 table" starts at 00:00:00 UTC, and I can add a fixed delay parameter to the output-data-set.

I appreciate your advice on the topic.

Cheers, Alx

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44183014/how-to-chain-azure-data-factory-pipelines

Comment: Thanks, I saw your linked post earlier, and I am using a delay. It kinda sucks to drop the activity just to edit the availability section, and it kinda sucks that there is no proper event triggering.